# Using std::make_*() idiom for object creation instead of constructor and the problem of dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

I want to use `make*()` functions for complex object creation like this:

```cpp
class Histogram {
public:
  Histogram(size_t, double, double){}
};

auto makeHistogramFromImage(Image image) {
  // deduce the parameters from image
  return Histogram(...);
}
```

I like it, cause it's more explicit than a constructor. The problem is, with a constructor `Histogram(Image)` I can use `std::make_shared<Histogram>(Image)`, but with the `makeHistogramFromImage` I can't do that.

My question is: is there an elegant way to do this, or do I have to create a separate method that would return a pointer?

Comment: If you have a `Histogram` constructor taking an `Image` object as argument, then you can just do e.g. `return Histogram(image);`.

Comment: "I can't do that" What exactly prevents you from?

Comment: make_shared is unrelated, it's a template to facilitate shorter code for creation of initialized smart pointer

Comment: "more explicit than constructor" - I'm not sure if that's a good thing. `std::make_shared` has a very specific purpose to it (1 memory allocation instead of 2), a standard later `std::make_unique` was added for symmetry, but that doesn't mean you should have factory functions for every type.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen make_unique is not about symmetry but about exception safety. Unrelated to the question, but figured I would mention it.

Comment: There are some features of C++ that rely on delegating to the constructor of the object.  `make_shared` is one example.  `vector::emplace_back` is another.  If you want to use these, then just use real constructors.  If, instead, you want to tightly control object creation (for example, lifetime control by ONLY creating histograms as shared_ptrs), then make a factory function, and make the constructor private.

Comment: I have no idea what is your problem. Even with this example I have no idea what is your intent. This works for me: https://godbolt.org/z/PersP4os8 So please [edit] your question and try provide more details what is your intent (for example: provide example of use of the API you are trying to design).

Comment: This may be an XY Problem.  Is there an "elegant way" to avoid using constructors in C++?  Probably not, in the opinion of most people, I suspect.  Constructors are pretty fundamental to the language.  `Histogram{image}` would be viewed as the most explicit way to say "Construct a `Histogram` from an `image`".

Comment: your motivation is not that clear. On the one hand you dont want a `Histogram(Image)` constructor on the other hand you want one. If it is about being explicit, you can declare the constructor `explicit`

Comment: It would help if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows exactly what you can and what you can't do.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `std::make_unique<Histogram>(makeHistogramFromImage(image))`.